# How to properly reference modals as of NativeScript 4

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular

I have built an app with NativeScript Angular (now on v4.1). I am using the code below to set a status bar color on Android, which works fine for "regular" views by using angular routing:

```
if (isAndroid) {
  if (app.android && device.sdkVersion >= '21') {
    const nativeColor = new Color('purple').android;
    const window = app.android.startActivity.getWindow();
    window.addFlags(android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
    app.android.startActivity.getWindow().setStatusBarColor(nativeColor);
  }
}
```

However, it does not work in a modal, where the colored status-bar turns to black. Anyone any ideas why this is? My best guess would be that a modal is not referenced by `app.android.startActivity.getWindow()` but I’m unclear as how to get it.

Not sure to what extent this is related, but also I am unable to set a different loading indicator on iOS in modals by using this code from the docs (again works fine in non-modal views):

```
if (isIOS) {
  var indicator = this.page.getViewById("spinner");
  indicator.ios.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.WhiteLarge;
}
```

Thanks for any pointers!

P.S.

Here is a [demo project](https://github.com/abhayastudios/so-51346704-statusbar) which displays the problem both with the status bar on Android, as well as not being able to set the activity indicator on iOS.

Comment: can u create the playground demo?

Comment: @bhavinjalodara sure! I edited my answer to include a demo project. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone reading this later on: I had some help on the NativeScript [forum](https://discourse.nativescript.org/t/how-to-properly-reference-modals-as-of-nativescript-4/6920) and did not yet accomplish setting the statusbar color on the modal, but I was able to span the background under the status bar in the modal component which is good enough for my purposes.

I was also able to change the ActivityIndicator in the modal simply by using an Angular `ViewChild` on the indicator element instead of finding it through `Page` (which turns out does not refer to the modal).

```
import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit, ViewChild, ElementRef } from "@angular/core";
import { ModalDialogParams } from "nativescript-angular/modal-dialog";
import { isIOS, isAndroid, device } from 'platform';
import * as app from "application";

declare var UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle: any;
declare var android: any;

@Component({
    template: `
        <StackLayout #root>
            <StackLayout orientation="horizontal">
                <ActivityIndicator #spinner id="spinner" busy="true"></ActivityIndicator>
                <ActivityIndicator busy="true"></ActivityIndicator>
            </StackLayout>
        </StackLayout>
    `
})
export class ModalTest implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
    @ViewChild('root') root: ElementRef;
    @ViewChild('spinner') spinner: ElementRef;

    constructor(
        public modalParams: ModalDialogParams
    ) {}

    public ngOnInit() {

        /* show large activity indicator on iOS */

        if (isIOS) {
            this.spinner.nativeElement.ios.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.WhiteLarge;
        }
    }

    public ngAfterViewInit() {
        if (isAndroid) {

            setTimeout(() => {
                if (app.android && device.sdkVersion >= '21') {
                    const dialog = this.root.nativeElement._dialogFragment.getDialog();
                    const window = dialog.getWindow();
                    window.addFlags(android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
                }
            },1);
        }
    }

    public closeModal() {
        this.modalParams.closeCallback();
    }
}
```